# Garbage collection of unclosed Scanner

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java.util.scanner

To get around the [skipping nextLine() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods), and to make the code cleaner, have I a couple of times used the following approach:

```
private String getInput() {
    return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}
```

This have not been any production code, just small projects, so I haven't cared much if this could give performance issues since I found the approach very convenient. I really like to use this method for all inputs and parse the return value.

To the question - is this a very bad practice? I does not feel good to not close the Scanner, but since the object gets out of reach, have I been thinking that the Scanner object should be garbage collected and therefore also closed. How does the gc handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not `close` it in this case otherwise `System.in` will be closed too such that you won't be able to get any new input, indeed if you execute this simple code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.close();
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine(); // -> Exception here
```

You will get the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The only real issue that I see with your approach is the fact that it can be inefficient if you call this method regularly as you create a new `Scanner` instance at each call, moreover it could be JDK implementation specific because if you have one implementation of `Scanner` that implements the method `finalize` it may close the `Scanner` which would lead to the error described above.

Comment: Could you explain the error above more thoroughly, I don't get the issue? And of course I understand its inefficient, but the performance affect must be _minimal_.

Comment: Check the method close of a Scanner, if you close a scanner it closes the source too which is System.in here, so you can't read the input stream anymore

Comment: if you do it a couple of times indeed the affect should be minimal, it depends on your use case

Comment: Great I see now, good explanation, tested your example too, it give me that error. Anyhow, I could not produce this error with my approach. Now I'm curious why this getInput() method don't cause any error.

Comment: simply because the scanner is never closed, it is simply garbage collected

Answer (score -1):

The `Scanner` has a `finalize()` method which will close any native resources when the object is GC'd.

Comment: But is this approach bad practice? If so, why?

Comment: I think it's bad practice , imagine creating new object for every single input instead of creating just one !! I suggest you edit your answer

Comment: I don't see any finalize method in scanner which JDK do you use?

Comment: Eh, yea well at `FileInputStream` level there's a `finalize()`.